# How to overflow the OVS-switch in SDN mininet? Whether how it to be done?

Tags: switch-statement, overloading, mininet, sdn, pox

I want to over flow the OVS-switch in Mininet by using the pox controller..Is it possible that we shrink the number of flow entry or we selected just one flow table in ovs-switch?

I am expecting the**mininet commands**which tells how to shrink the number of flow tables or flow entry